# How to access session in different method of codeigniter?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter.
How do i use session objects to pass value from one method to another method in controller?

I've loaded the library in my constructor class:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

1st function:

```
public function display()
{
$data = array(
'word' => 'hello'
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
```

2nd function:

```
public function validate()
{
$word_generated = $this->session->userdata('word');
}
```

But i'm not able to access the session value in the second method.

The code works fine if i access the session within the same method:

```
public function display()
{
$data = array(
'word' => 'hello'
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
$word_generated = $this->session->userdata('word');
}
```

Y am i not able to access it in second method then? Please guide.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your code seems fine. Have you checked if cookies are enabled on the machine you are working with?

Comment: Ya i think.. In my config.php, i have the following entries..
$config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']  = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']  = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;

Comment: Those are the default values and they are fine as well. Try using something like firebug to check if the cookies are actually being set.

Comment: 1) are you showing us controller code, or custom library code?

Comment: This is the controller code..

Answer (score 2):

In order to access the *session* data from method to method (or page-to-page), you should do a redirect.

**For instance:**

```
public function display() {
    $data = array(
        'word' => 'hello'
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    redirect('your_controller/validate');
 }

 public function validate() {
     $word_generated = $this->session->userdata('word');
 }
```

If you're simply trying to share a variable with two methods in the same controller on the same call, you have two options:

**1. Set a public property for you controller class:**

```
class Your_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $word;
    public function display() {
       $this->word = 'hello';
       $this->validate();
    }

    public function validate() {
       $word_generated = $this->word;
    }
}
```

**2. Just pass the variable to the method normally:**

```
class Your_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public $word;
    public function display() {
       $this->validate('hello');
    }

    public function validate($word='') {
       $word_generated = $word;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Using CI 1.7.x, I found an error in my webapp where it just stopped reading my session_data. What I did to correct this was change the $config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] in config.php to TRUE; and it started working again. Of course, in the log files a cookie corruption error kept popping up...

Hope it helps